# Issue Of Width In RDLC Report Display in ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I have design a rdlc report in a4 size(8.5 x 11.0). 
 When i display report into reportviewer it will not display properly in terms of width.

Below is the screenshot:

[image]

I also write few code for report viewer as under :

```
 <div id="dvRpt" runat="Server" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 440px">
   <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" ShowPrintButton="true" AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="true"  Width="93%" Height="400px" runat="server">
   </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It displays good in Mozilla Firefox but looks stretched on Google Chrome and modern versions of Internet Explorer.

Digging into the issue, I found that the contents of the report are inside a table cell with id `oReportCell` like this:

```
<div id="oReportDiv">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="oReportCell"><!-- Report content goes here --></td>
            <td height="0" width="100%"><!-- Empty cell with problematic width --></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The fix for me is to remove the width="100%" of that cell. That's a bit tricky, since the report is generated inside an iframe and in turn inside other frames. Forcing a width with CSS doesn't work.

I've created this piece of JavaScript that works on the page where the report viewer is generated. It needs to listen to load events of the frames for when you navigate through the pages of the report.

Replace the ID with your report viewer ID:

```
(function() {
    var _init = function() {
        var reportControl, frameId, frame;
        reportControl = document.getElementById('ReportViewer1'); // ID of the ReportViewer control
        if (!reportControl || !reportControl.ClientController) return;
        frameId = reportControl.ClientController.m_docMapReportFrameID;
        if (!frameId) return;
        frame = document.getElementById(frameId);
        if (!frame || !frame.addEventListener) return;
        frame.addEventListener('load', (function(frame) {
            return function(e) {
                _reportFrameLoaded(frame);
            };
        })(frame), false);
    },
    _reportFrameLoaded = function(frame) {
        var innerDoc;
        innerDoc = frame.contentDocument;
        frame = innerDoc.getElementById('report');
        if (!frame) return;
        frame.addEventListener('load', (function(frame) {
            return function(e) {
                _innerReportFrameLoaded(frame);
            };
        })(frame), false);
        // If the frame already has content, it may be loaded before 
        // this load function has run. Call the child onload function now
        if (frame.contentDocument) {
            _innerReportFrameLoaded(frame);
        }
    },
    _innerReportFrameLoaded = function(frame) {
        var innerDoc, cell1;
        innerDoc = frame.contentDocument;
        cell1 = innerDoc.getElementById('oReportCell');
        if (!cell1) return;
        if (cell1.nextSibling.hasAttribute('width')) {
            cell1.nextSibling.removeAttribute('width');
        }
    };
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _init, false);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

make ReportViewer's width="100%"  and try

```
<div id="dvRpt" runat="Server" style="width: 100%; height: 440px">
   <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" ShowPrintButton="true" AsyncRendering="false" SizeToReportContent="true"  Width="100%" Height="400px" runat="server">
   </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Comment: try to remove "overflow: auto;" and check

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" > 
<div style="Width:auto;">
   <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" AsyncRendering="False" SizeToReportContent="True">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
</form
```

Answer (score 0):

apply just this on your css

```
   <style>
         table{
        width:100%;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" width="100%"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

This will do it.